# How to select a specific field from a table based on what a user selects on a form using VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, query-string

I have never done this before rather I search for answers but I have not been able to find what I am looking for. I will try to be brief so forgive me.  I have a table that I want to pull data from and insert into a temporary table to use for later.  The table looks like this

Student,Grade,School,Day1,Day10,Day20,Day30,Day40,Day50..  This continues to 180 days...

The day fields are yes/no fields.  What I would like to do is query the specific day field and look for true and insert the results into a temp table.  I have a form set up that I select the days and I use a CASE statement for each selection and run an unique insert query for each "day" selected on the form,(18 queries) but what I would like to do is somehow get rid of that and take the "day" selection from my form and use it to create a sql insert query that says something like look at the "day" field from the form for the value of true. And as I change the day selection the query is updated dynamically that way when there is a change I do not have to change 18 different sql statements.  I have been using this technique in multiple applications within my database. So rather than 18 different statements the statement would be created based on the selection on the form.
OK, so I sound like an idiot but I have spent an entire day looking for a solution so I give up surely this is not that difficult for real programmers. So thanks for any help.  Below is the code that I got of the net and have been Frankensteining for my use it is not complete and it gives a Too few parameters error which I cannot figure out why that is happening other than the entire thing is wrong.  Well if someone can help that would be great.

```vb
Sub RB_AOI()

Dim dy 
'Run day from form 
dy = "[Forms]![RB_Main]![RunDay].value" 
Dim db As DAO.Database 
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef 
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb

'This is not my code I know it is not an insert query but I was only testing at this point to see if it would do anything.

Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", "PARAMETERS dy LONG; " & _
    "SELECT * FROM [historical_enrollment_master] WHERE columname = dy")
'Column names match the Run Day from the form

'I believe this is where the criteria for the named field belongs.... 

With qdf 
  .Parameters("dy") = True 
  Set rst = .OpenRecordset
End With

With rst
    MsgBox .Fields("Dy")
    .Close
End With

qdf.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: It chopped up my code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: _The table looks like this ..._ and from that it tells, that you need to look into _normalisation_ of your table schemas.

Comment: Hy, check my profile and send me a mail. We can look at it via zoom. Afterwards we will post the anwser of your question here. There is a lot to be done to make this work, so instead of writing a complete essay about how to fix the above, just send me a mail and lets make it work.